# push values to sails.js collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm working in a little project in sails.js, i have two models: Empresa and Noticia, the Empresa Model have a collection of Noticia and the Noticia model have a empresa relation:

Empresa.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    nombre: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    activa:{
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    usuarios:{
      collection: 'User',
      via: 'empresa'
    },
    noticias:{
      collection: 'Noticia',
      via: 'empresa'
    }
  }
};
```

Noticia.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    titulo:{
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    texto:{
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    publicada:{
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    empresa:{
      model: 'Empresa',
      via: 'noticias'
    }
  }
```

in the front end i have a angular app whose is gonna add Noticias to the noticias collection one by one, how can i do it?

EmpresaNoticias angular.js controller

```
.controller('EmpresaUsuarioController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Noticia, Empresa) {

    $scope.addNoticia = function(){
        $scope.newNoticia.empresa = $routeParams.EmpresaId;
        Noticia.save($scope.newNoticia, function(noticia){
            Empresa.update({id: $routeParams.EmpresaId}, {noticias: noticia.id}, function(){
                $location.path('/noticia/'+ noticia.id);
            })
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

});
```

i know that in javascript exists the function push to add values to an array, and i want to do something like that in sails.js, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a dumb answer, D: i just had to change a little bit the angular.js controler, like this:

```
.controller('EmpresaUsuarioController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Noticia, Empresa) {

    $scope.addNoticia = function(){
        $scope.newNoticia.empresa = $routeParams.EmpresaId;
        Noticia.save($scope.newNoticia, function(noticia){
           $location.path('/noticia/'+ noticia.id);
        }, function(error){
      });
    };
});
```